# Way to list all procedures present in the form of proc foo::bar {} in a Tcl file

Tags: namespaces, tcl, proc

I am trying to get the list of procedure names of the below code:

```
namespace eval foo::bar {
    namespace export fun1
    namespace export fun2
}

proc foo::bar::fun1 {} {
    
}

proc foo::bar::fun2 {} {
    
}

proc fun3 {} {
}
```

It should return
list of procedure : fun1 fun2 fun3

```
set f [open $filepath]
set data [read $f]
close $f

foreach {dummy procName} [regexp -all -inline -line {^[\s:]*proc (\S+)} $data] {
    puts "Found procedure $procName"
}
```

But not getting the expected output.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Tcl's own introspection features to get this info.  First `source` or run the code which defines these procedures, then run:

```
foreach procName [info procs *] {
    puts "Found procedure $procName"
}
```

For more details see https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/info.htm#M37 .  Note that you can use a more specific pattern than `*`, e.g. `foo::bar::*` to get just the procs in that namespace.